# Identifying Manual vs. Automated in a Data Frame

Tags: r, group-by

I have a data set representing applications.  There is a string column called "Text.".  When the string column is populated, this means the record was manually handled.  When the string column is populated by a "?", this means the record was automatically handled.  There are multiple rows representing a single application.

If an application has one row that indicates it was handled manually, and another row that indicates it was handled automatically, it always reverts to manually handled.

Data Frame:

```
App     Text
1       Hello
2       Happening
3       Sly
3       ?
4       Hat
5       Hello
5       Juice
6       ?
7       Hello
7       Happening
7       ?
8       ?
```

I want to create a new column which identifies how the record was handled.  I've attempted some group_by statements and counts of "?", but that didn't pan out.

Desired Output:

```
App     Decision
1       Manual
2       Manual
3       Manual
4       Manual
5       Manual
6       Automated
7       Manual
8       Automated
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one option.  After grouping by 'App', `summarise` to create the 'Decision' based on whether `all` elements in 'Text' are `?`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(App) %>%
  summarise(Decision = c( "Manual", "Automated")[all(Text == "?") + 1])
# A tibble: 8 x 2
#    App Decision 
#  <int> <chr>    
#1     1 Manual   
#2     2 Manual   
#3     3 Manual   
#4     4 Manual   
#5     5 Manual   
#6     6 Automated
#7     7 Manual   
#8     8 Automated
```

---

Or as @CalumYou suggested, an `if/else` would make this more readable

```
df1 %>%
   group_by(App) %>%
   summarise(Decision = if(all(Text == "?")) "Automated" else "Manual")
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(App = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 8L), Text = c("Hello", "Happening", "Sly", "?", "Hat", "Hello", 
"Juice", "?", "Hello", "Happening", "?", "?")),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Comment: Could also `summarise(Decision = if_else(all(Text == "?"), "Automated", "Manual"))` which reads a bit more like you might say it out loud

Comment: @CalumYou  Yes, since it is a single TRUE/FALSE, i guess `if/else` would be more appropriate.  do you agre